# Location from which QGIS reads datum transforms

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, datum

I am trying to transform coordinates from the Adindan datum (EPSG:4201) to the WGS-1984 datum (EPSG:4326) using the transform [Adindan to WGS 84 (6) (EPSG:1105)](https://epsg.org/transformation_1105/Adindan-to-WGS-84-6.html).
But when I try to select it, QGIS only shows me the EPSG:1100, EPSG:1106 and EPSG:1103 transforms.

[image: QGIS datum transformation select]

when I look in the srs.db file in the resources folder of QGIS installation, the transform is there.
[image: srs.db with epsg1105 datum transformation]

So where QGIS store this info (abou datum transformation)?
How can I get QGIS to use this transformation?
Do I need to create a custom one?

Obs.: I have data that are in Senegal, in the Adindan datum. I want to transform these data that are in Senegal, in the Adinda datum, to the WGS-1984 datum using the EPSG:1105 transformation (which is valid for Senegal).[image: Adindan to WGS84 (6) - Usage: Senegal - onshore]

My problem is that this EPSG:1105 transformation is not available in QGIS (at least not in the UI).
But it does appear in the srs.db file (which is apparently not where QGIS reads this information from).
So the question is where QGIS reads the datum transformation information that is displayed in the UI.

Comment: The area of use for 1105 covers Senegal https://epsg.org/transformation_1105/Adindan-to-WGS-84-6.html.

Comment: yes, i want to transform some data that is from Senegal.

Comment: Into a coordinate system that valid in Ethiopia and Sudan? Because there is no transformation that can do that you must find a common coordinate system and convert the data from Senegal and Ethiopia into that common one.

Comment: no, I must have expressed myself badly.
I have data that are in Senegal, in the Adindan datum.
I want to transform these data that are in Senegal, in the Adinda datum, to the WGS-1984 datum using the EPSG:1105 transformation (which is valid for Senegal).
my question is that this EPSG:1105 transformation is not available in QGIS (at least not in the UI).
But it does appear in the srs.db file (which is apparently not where QGIS reads this information from).
So the question is where QGIS reads the datum transformation information that is displayed in the UI.

Comment: Maybe you should contact the EPSG organization and ask. There seems to be something strange. If you look at the transformation https://epsg.org/transformation_1105/Adindan-to-WGS-84-6.html, it is really valid in Senagal, but by the database the Adindan datum is not valid in Senagal https://epsg.org/crs_4201/Adindan.html? QGIS is checking the areas of validity when it shows items in the UI.

Comment: @user30184. thank you very much for your help (indicating that the filter is the datum usage area)